# C# giving radio buttons and panels a value

Tags: c#, radio-button

I am very new to C# and am trying to make a form program with a lot of radio buttons, i was hoping to have something to the effect of

```
radioButton1.value = 1;
radioButton2.value = 2;
panel1.Value = Selected radiobuttons value;
```

or just something like that without having to write out so many if/switch statements.

Comment: All Controls have a Tag property which will let you store anything. The bool that marks the current state is called `Checked`. Note that 'Selected' != 'Checked' here and in all other controls!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LINQ` to get the selected button.
Assume that your radioButtons are in form, so the variable `this` means the class form.

```cs
var selectedButton = this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                          .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);

Console.WriteLine(selectedButton.Text);
```